# Python - Processing inputs from STDIN without converting to integer(SPOJ INOUTEST)

Tags: python, string, io, integer

I was trying to solve this http://www.spoj.pl/problems/INOUTEST/ problem.

INPUT:
The first line of input contains a single integer N (1 ≤ N ≤ 106), denoting the number of lines to follow. Each of these lines contains two space-separated integers a and b (|a|, |b| ≤ 40,000).

OUTPUT:
For each pair a and b, write a single line of output containing the value of a × b.
My code was this which ran till 17.03sec:

```
import sys
import psyco
psyco.full()

def main():
    s = sys.stdin
    t = int(s.readline())
    for l in s:
        n, m = map(int, l.split())
        print n*m

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I changed

```
t = int(s.readline())
```

to

```
t = s.readline()
```

which ran till 16.62 sec. This made me realize that the less I convert strings to integers, the faster will my code run. The fastest solution is about 2.5sec. I am curious about this because I solve all problems in SPOJ with python and I am trying to learn. Thank You.

Comment: What is the question? :)

Comment: The question is about multiplying 2 numbers which are given in t lines. This is to test the fastest I/O to process large inputs.

Comment: I am quite sure it will be faster if you write code that uses C library underneath, and/or implement your own parsing functions.

Comment: With my experiments the fastest way to take inputs in with python is sys.stdin which is mentioned in the python library. Can you give me hint to create my own functions?

Comment: @Rishi: I cannot give any specific hint, since I am not yet familiar with Python. In C, I use `fread` (`read([size])` is the equivalent in Python), and read everything into a big buffer, write my own function to parse and print number, and write everything at once with `fwrite` (can't find equivalent in Python).

Comment: Actually we can take the whole input in an array with file.read(). But, that will not be faster than this. Need something more.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to cut 4 seconds off your time (down to 12.52) by not using a map inside the for loop.  Instead I just converted each line of input into two integers in the most straightforward way I could think of.

```
ab = line.split()
a = int(ab[0])
b = int(ab[1])
```

The only other difference between your solution and the one I came up with is that I used `raw_input()` instead of `s.readline()`to read the initial line of input (the number of test cases to follow).  Since this only gets executed once, I doubt it makes a measurable impact on the run time.

Comment: Hi Bill: Thank You. with `s.readline()` instead of `raw_input()` my solution gave 12.45. Further I saved `i=int` and used `a = i(ab[0])` and `b = i(ab[1])` for converting to int. This made the time to 12.14. What more can be done?